# Why does my CSS only affect the IMG when put in a div?

Tags: html, css

I've just learnt about classes and when using a class on an image to center it, alter the size, etc., it doesn't work unless I put it in a div.

I'd like to know why that's the case! I've linked the .css with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">` in head of the index.html.

```
<!--<div class="plskiyo">-->
    <img class="plskiyo.img" src="images/spicy-kiyo.jpg" alt="image has broke">
<!--</div>-->

.plskiyo img
{
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Throwaway Account. Could you please provide your whole HTML code, or at least a frame which contains `html` and `body` tags?

Comment: @CuongHoang Thank you very much for being a nice human.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount Just keep learning pal !
a week from now you will know how to inject jsfiddle or use built-in html-css edit of stackoverflow. its just easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.plskiyo img` line in your CSS is called a selector; it is what is used to associate DOM elements with the styles that you defined.

Just `.plskiyo` would select all elements with the `.plskiyo` class. `.plskiyo img` selects all `img` tags that are within any tags with the `.plskiyo` class.

There's a lot to know about CSS selectors. Start your reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thank you! This is what I get for staying up over 24 hours and trying to learn. I can't believe I missed this.

Comment: It might also be good for your understanding to look up the CSS box model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model It should help you understand why your img needs to be in a div to be centered. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `.img` from `class="plskiyo.img"` in your html.

```css
img.plskiyo {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="plskiyo" src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all" alt="image has broke">
```

You could also change the css to just `img { ... }` and remove `class="plskiyo"` from the img-tag, if you only have one image on the whole page (or same styling for all images). Or you could name the css class `.plskiyo { ... }` and it will still work. Having the `img.plskiyo` guarantees that your class is only applicable on images. These are just some explanation so you could get an idea of how this works. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Simply using css

```
 <img src="images/spicy-kiyo.jpg" alt="image has broke">

.img
{
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```